# Multiple WordPress installations - single domain in wpengine

Tags: wordpress

I am moving my WordPress site to wpengine. My current site has 2 WordPress installations on the same domain (not multisite, just 2 different installations, one in the root and another in a sub-folder)

Is it possible to replicate this structure in a wpengine personal plan? Or do I have to enable multisite and do this?

I noticed that with the personal plan there is no way to add a new database. What happens if I share the same database between the WordPress installations (different table prefix) and move the entire sub-folder with the 2nd WordPress installation to wpengine? Would that work?

I can always try and do this but am afraid it might break something.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I'm the founder of WP Engine.  A few answers:

1. We don't *quite* support it that way.  You can have two installs which you can *access* under one account, but not in the same shared filesystem.
2. Typically you'd need to be at the Professional plan to support more than one installation, however please contact our support team (email, phone, or live chat) and tell them what you need and how much traffic the two sites get, and they might be able to help out.
3. You should *not* use Multisite in any event -- that's not the same thing as having two installs.  If you actually want Multisite -- a shared base system with different content at different URLs, that's possible too but requires some configuration and some export/import.  This is due to how WordPress works and isn't specific to hosting with us.
4. Correct, we do not support more than one database *per installation*, but again we do support what you need, and with separate databases.  Tech support can help you through that.
5. Please feel free to use our tech support for further answers!  Of course there's nothing wrong with posting here as well, but we are here to help you.

Answer (score 0):

From what I tested this should be possible with some restrictions:

- you only get ONE database, so you need different table prefix
- WP Engine will only manage ONE installation in your account (i.e. you can only create a snapshot of one install, set the domain of one install, backup one install, etc.)

So your second site can only be accessed via a subfolder (not via own domain or subdomain).
Also you need take care of things like backup (and maybe security) of the second site yourself.